# What's the meaning of "I can't imagine why."?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, british-english, sentence

Does it mean "The answer is obvious to me." in a sarcastic way, or does it mean "I really don't know the reason."? I am inclined to go with the former. Surprisingly googling doesn't help.

Secondly, is this sentence more common in British English?

Edit: [Here](https://youtu.be/gEUF87lqdUo?t=2m4s) is the scene from 'Harry Potter and the Half-blood Prince' that prompted me to ask this question. Here Harry appears to be sarcastic. But I have heard this same sentence used truthfully, though I can't find any references now.

Edit2: [Here](https://youtu.be/g1q4w4wq8Cw?t=1m24s) is another example from 'Friends' where again its used in a sarcastic way.

Comment: The first one..

Comment: I can't imagine why this question is likely to be closed. But I can hardly imagine why it was asked anyway.

Comment: It can mean both, depending on context. Sarcasm depends on context, and just about any phrase can be sincere or sarcastic.

Comment: As @KhalilMair says:   it can be sarcastic. It is a cliché  snooty remark.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You mean "I can imagine why..." don't you?

Comment: @Hugh It is hardly sarcastic. It is often just a way of emphasising one's surprise at something. *I can't imagine why I am still constipated, I have been eating prunes all the week*.

Comment: @WS2, Can a phrase be encliitic?  When  "I can't imagine why!"  is tacked onto the end of a paragraph, it is sarcastic more often than not. Isn't it?

Comment: @Hugh It is a different figure to sarcasm, which usually points at an individual(s). It can be used in that way. (*I can't imagine why he thought I had taken the day off, he knows I have far too much work to do*.) But  often it is not. I'm not sure what one would call it.

Comment: @Centaurus: I can't deny my first usage above was supposed to be ironic at the time. But not the second, since I take it for granted "ironic meaning reversal" is common in *all* languages. And 16 hours after it was posted, I'm having *real* difficulty understanding why it's still open - ironically enough, perhaps that's because some people who might otherwise have closevoted took exception to the supercilious tone of my comment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  My difficulty in understanding exactly what you meant was  because of the word "but".   e.g. "I can imagine but I cannot/can hardly imagine" makes sense to me, whereas "I can't imagine but I can't imagine/can hardly imagine" sounded weird to me.

Comment: @Centaurus: But they're two completely different things one might have difficulty imagining. First, *Why is it likely to be closed?* (ironic, since at the I assumed it would be closed almost immediately as "trivial"), and second, *Why did OP feel the need to ask the question at all?* ("semi-ironic", since I do actually have some difficulty understanding the motivation). I just included *hardly* on the second one because if pressed I suppose I'd have to reluctantly accept that he asked because he genuinely thought there was the possibility of an unambiguous Yes/No type of answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers   As you certainly know better than I, the written word doesn't always convey what we mean it to.  I missed the irony in the first sentence and thought it was a typo, because of "but".

Comment: @Centaurus: Happens to me all the time when I'm reading "chatty" online posts. Part of the problem being that it's a text-only medium, but most of us have most of our interactions in the far richer context of real life (where there's usually a much fuller context, plus we've got intonation, facial expressions, body language, etc. to carry more information). Anyway, as you probably know perfectly well, I *am* somewhat prone to typos and other careless mistakes, so even if you were wrong on that occasion, you're quite right to be "suspicious" of my text! :)

Comment: Please see my edit to the post for additional context.

Answer (score 4):

When used without irony/sarcasm, it means "I do not understand why this situation occurred.  (And I'm somewhat surprised.)"

When used ironically/sarcastically (which is perhaps slightly more common), it of course means the opposite:  "The reason for this situation is glaringly obvious."

(At least this is true in the US, where the expression is reasonably common.)

Comment: If it can be used both ways, how to tell the difference. I've added further context as an edit to my post.

Comment: @Prometheus - Basically you tell the difference the same way you tell if something is really a question or not -- the tone of voice.  Very crudely, if used without sarcasm the sentence will end with a slightly rising pitch (similar to a "real" question, which it in effect is), but if used with sarcasm the pitch will remain monotone or drop slightly near the end (similar to a rhetorical question).  (But before anyone jumps on me, note that I said *very crudely*.  I'm sure there's some technical term, and someone will say it does rise but it trills or some such.)